# why does sizeof(*pointer) gives output as 1?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *str1 = "Abcde";
    char str2[] = "Abcde";

    printf("sizeof(str1) = %d, sizeof(str2) = %d sizeof(*str1) = %d",
        sizeof(str1), sizeof(str2),sizeof(*str1));

    return 0;
}
```

the above code gives output of `sizeof(*str1) =1`. can somebody explain why I expected it to be the `sizeof("Abcde")` as it's dereferencing.

Comment: Because `*str` is a character, and the size of a character is 1 by definition.

Comment: @wildplasser Answers go in the funnily-named "answer section" mate

Comment: By writing *str you reference the value stored in the address pointed by str, which is a char of size 1 (byte).

Comment: There you go ...

Comment: It can be confusing, but your pointer is `str1`. When you declare and initialize the pointer `char *str1 = "Abcde";` The `char *` is the type (*pointer-to-char*). You could do `char *str1;` and then `str1 = "Abcde";` if that helps emphasize what the pointer is. Thereafter, when you *dereference* the pointer, e.g. `*str1`, you remove one-level of *indirection* so dereferencing a *pointer-to-char* simply leaves type `char`. Array/Pointer conversion is covered here: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Comment: The correct format to print a `size_t` value, such as the value of a `sizeof` expression, is `"%zu"`, not `"%d"`. Using `"%d"` may or may not work, depending on the implementation. (Some older implementations don't support `"%zu"`; if that's the case, you can convert to a known type: `printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)sizeof whatever);`

Answer (score 4):

The other answers correctly explain why `sizeof (*str) == 1` but they don't address your understandable confusion.

C arrays are in a sense second-class citizens. Array objects are actual objects, like objects of any other type (integer, structure, etc.), but the language provides very few operations that operate directly on arrays.

Instead, array objects are usually manipulated via pointers to their elements.

In your example, you have:

```
char *str1 = "Abcde";
```

The string literal `"Abcde"` corresponds to an anonymous array object of type `char[6]` (5 for the length of the string plus 1 for the terminating `'\0'` null character). Thus `sizeof "Abcde" == 6`.

But `str1` is not a pointer to that array object; it's just a pointer to its initial element, which holds the character `'A'`. If we want to access the other elements of the array (the characters `'b'`, `'c'`, and so on), we need to perform *pointer arithmetic* to advance a pointer through the elements of the array object.

So initially, `*str1 == 'A'` -- but after `++str1`, `*str1 == 'b'`.

If you want to print the value of the string, you can do:

```
printf("%s\n", str1);
```

and the `printf` function will internally do the pointer arithmetic needed to advance through the characters of the string.

And that's why `sizeof (*str) == 1`. It only points to a single element of the array object. We can use it to access the other elements, but the pointer value itself doesn't carry any information about how big the array is. (That's what the terminating `'\0'` is for, so we can recognize the end of the string without knowing in advance how big it is.)

Note that you *can* have a pointer to an entire array object:

```
char (*array_ptr)[6] = &"Abcde";
```

and `sizeof *array_ptr == 6` -- but that's not as useful as you might expect. `array_ptr` can only point to an array of exactly 6 elements, and since functions like `printf` and `strlen` require `char*` pointers, you can't directly manipulate the array using `array_ptr`. (Pointers to array objects do show up when you're dealing with multidimensional arrays -- arrays of arrays.)

Pointers to array elements, as opposed to entire array objects, are much more flexible, and the standard library uses them extensively. The drawback is that you have to keep track of the size of the array yourself, for example by passing it as an extra argument or by using a sentinel value like `'\0'` to mark the end of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Because `*str1` is a `char`.

And a `char` is a byte.

And a byte has size of one.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(*str1)` is `1` because:

1. `str1` is a `char *`
2. `*str1` is a `char`
3. The size of `char` is `1` by definition.

Once you assign `"Abcde"` to a `char *`, you lose all context of that original string, including its size.

Answer (score 0):

There are two syntactical forms of `sizeof`:

- `sizeof (TYPE)` , where TYPE is a type (such as  `int` , `char`, etc)
- `sizeof expr` , where `expr` is any expression (such as `1` or `*ptr`, etc)

Note the absence of `()` in the second form! In any case, the `TYPE` or `expr` wont be evaluated (as the standard says: `only for its size`)

Note: there is a third (hidden) form:

- `sizeof object` ; where object is some identifier

In the case of:

```
char buff[123];
size_t sz = sizeof buff;
```

, the `sz` will be `123`, so the `buff` wont be promoted/degraded to a pointer.

Note: the `sizeof` operator has a very strong precedence (check the table!) so after

```
sz = sizeof 1+2;
```

sz will equal `sizeof(int) + 2`

In your case, `*str` will be a a character, with value 'A': its size will be one: the size of a character.

That's all.

Comment: Calling out the absence of parentheses in the second form, although technically correct, is potentially confusing because it suggests that parentheses must not appear in that form, which is untrue.  Parentheses may appear in it because they may appear in an expression, and they may be *needed* in that form precedence purposes.

Comment: Also, the so-called third form is just a special case of the second form, because the identifier of an object serves as an expression all by itself.

Comment: Adding the unneeded parenthesis is even more *confusing*: it starts looking like a function call. (whichi is impossible in the `sizeof(TYPE)` case). And yes: purely syntactical `(expr)` is the same as `expr`. And the introduction of my *third* form was purely for didactic reasons.

Comment: If one confuses `sizeof` with a function and therefore uses parentheses where they are unneeded, one still gets the wanted result.  If one thinks parentheses are forbidden, on the other hand, then one will sometimes either get the wrong result or suppose that there is no way to get the wanted one.